# Add bullet points in mermaid diagram

Tags: markdown, diagram, mermaid

I would like to add bullet points like these:

- This is a bullet point

in a node of a mermaid diagram. We could use a - as list, but I would like to have the bullet. Here is some reproducible code:

```
flowchart LR
    A[Node 1] --> B[Node 2: \n-A\n-B]
```

Output:

[image]

Does anyone know how to change the - to a bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown lists are not natively supported in Mermaid. When you try it, for example

```
mylist newLines["`- Line1
    - Line 2
    - Line 3`"]
```

you get a message *Unsupported markdown: list*.

However, you can add the character manually, as in your current code with a literal `-`. There are some options, although neither is very quick to type. In the code below two font-awesome icons and various representations of the bullet character, i.e., html code `#8226`, html character name `bull`, Unicode •.

```
flowchart LR
    A[Node 1] --> B["Node 2: \nfa:fa-genderless font-awesome\nfa:fa-caret-right fa arrow\n#8226; html code\n#bull; html named\n• Unicode"]
```

[image]

For lists it may be better-looking to left-align the text:

```
flowchart LR
    A[Node 1] --> B["Node 2:\nfa:fa-genderless font-awesome\nfa:fa-caret-right fa arrow\n#8226; html code\n#bull; html named\n• Unicode"]
    style B text-align:left
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marijn, bedankt! Your code works perfectly!